# How to send HTML content to ASP.NET MVC JSON function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my jQuery code
and the next is my json function to hanlde this jquery code that named `InsertMatlabJson`.

The problem is no text comes in to the .NET json function. . .

```js
    function insert() {
       var url = '<%=Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Matlab/InsertMatlabJson";
       var text = document.getElementById('MainContent_FreeTextBox1').value
   $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {  text: text},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                //your success code
                alert("opk");
            },
            error: function () {
                //your error code
                alert("no");
            }
        }); 
}
```

and this is my Json function in ASP.NET MVC

```
 public JsonResult InsertMatlabJson(string text)
    {
```

}

Comment: Do you want to send html through the query and receive it on the function as the text variable?

Comment: Is your question, that in ASP.NET MVC you are not recieving anything in the text parameter?

Comment: Try changing: type: 'GET' to type: 'POST'

Comment: yes,I recive simple text (Hi)!;But I don't recive (<p>Hi</p>);

Comment: any ways of my friends not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
[AllowHtml]
public JsonResult InsertMatlabJson(string text)
{

}
```

Comment: For this answer to be useful to others you should add a brief explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problems. A "do this" type answer doesn't help anyone improve their code.